# Recursive Interpolation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, interpolation

I am working on a browser game which includes cubic interpolation in many dimensions. I need to take a set of values and a set of coordinates and output the estimated value that point in nD space would have. I have found some great tutorials for 1d cubic interpolation, and some examples of nD cubic interpolation in c++ (Both [here](https://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic)). The problem is that this c++ code uses many pointers and bit shifters, both of which I don't think JS has.

1D cubic interpolation is long, but it looks like this for whoever is interested:

f(a, b, c, d, x) =  b + 0.5 * x*(c - a + x*(2*a - 5*b + 4*c - d + x*(3*(b - c) + d - a))),    Where a-d are known values, and x is a value between 0 and 1 that determines the points relative placement between b and c

Js:

```
function interpolate(p, x){
    return p[1] + 0.5 * x*(p[2] - p[0] + x*(2*p[0] - 5*p[1] + 4*p[2] - p[3] + x*(3*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0])));
}
```

2d interpolation can be achieved simply like this:

g(a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, d<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>, c<sub>3</sub>, d<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>4</sub>, b<sub>4</sub>, c<sub>4</sub>, d<sub>4</sub>, x, y) =

f(f(a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>1</sub>, y), f(a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, d<sub>2</sub>, y), f(a<sub>3</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>, c<sub>3</sub>, d<sub>3</sub>, y), f(a<sub>4</sub>, b<sub>4</sub>, c<sub>4</sub>, d<sub>4</sub>, y), x)

Js:

```
function interpolate2d(arr, x, y){
  let a = [
    interpolate(arr[0], y),
    interpolate(arr[1], y),
    interpolate(arr[2], y),
    interpolate(arr[3], y),
  ];
  return interpolate(a, x);
}
```

3d is the same way:

```
function interpolate3d(arr, x, y, z){
  let a = [
    interpolate2d(arr[0], y, z),
    interpolate2d(arr[1], y, z),
    interpolate2d(arr[2], y, z),
    interpolate2d(arr[3], y, z)
  ];
  return interpolate(a, x);
}
```

I'm new to Js, (just came from c++ and java) and don't know many of the extra features. I haven't found anything online, except for `Array.reduce()` (don't know how that would work with nested arrays) and the recursive c++ code from the link above:

```
double nCubicInterpolate (int n, double* p, double coordinates[]) {
    assert(n > 0);
    if (n == 1) {
        return cubicInterpolate(p, *coordinates);
    }
    else {
        double arr[4];
        int skip = 1 << (n - 1) * 2;
        arr[0] = nCubicInterpolate(n - 1, p, coordinates + 1);
        arr[1] = nCubicInterpolate(n - 1, p + skip, coordinates + 1);
        arr[2] = nCubicInterpolate(n - 1, p + 2*skip, coordinates + 1);
        arr[3] = nCubicInterpolate(n - 1, p + 3*skip, coordinates + 1);
        return cubicInterpolate(arr, *coordinates);
    }
}
```

What would the Js function to replicate this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation to JavaScript can be:

```
function nCubicInterpolate(p, coordinates) {
    if (coordinates.length == 1) {
        return cubicInterpolate(p, coordinates[0]);
    } else {
        let fewerCoordinates = coordinates.slice(1);
        let arr = p.map(hyperplane => nCubicInterpolate(hyperplane, fewerCoordinates));
        return cubicInterpolate(arr, coordinates[0]);
    }
}
```

Note that the parameter `n` is not needed in JavaScript, as the length of the `coordinates` array argument corresponds to it. Also the nesting level of `p` should be that same `n`. JavaScript has no compile-time type checking, so that liberty comes to our advantage here: no pointers; `p` is an array, but it can be an array of numbers, or an array of array of numbers, or ...etc.

To be complete, the `cubicInterpolate` function is as you specified in the question:

```
function cubicInterpolate(p, x) {
    return p[1] + 0.5 * x*(p[2] - p[0] + x*(2*p[0] - 5*p[1] + 4*p[2] - p[3] + x*(3*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0])));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't line 6 of nCubicInterpolate be `return cubicInterpolate(arr, coordinates[0]);` instead of `return cubicInterpolate(arr, coordinates);`?

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure.